# Ubuntu 18.04 Unity - Can't login to my Ubuntu SSO account from Unity Control Center

Tags: unity, login, ubuntu-one, online-accounts, 18.04

I am using **Ubuntu 18.04** with **Unity 7**.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qltej.png)
of problem

When I entered the credentials as shown in screenshot in settings (*unity-control-center*) and pressed enter, nothing happens. Is it related to missing of some gnome packages? I tried installing *gnome-control-center* and adding account from there, still no luck. I have *gnome-online-accounts* package installed. Is there something I am missing?

EDIT:

The problem seems to be with the UI. I tried doing the same thing with *gnome-control-center*, but still there is not button. Pressing enter does not work either

Comment: Did you remove any snap related packages?

Comment: did not remove any? i just installed spotify via snap before doing this

Comment: Is snapd-login-service installed and running?

Comment: yep, i can login with sudo snap login , but it does not add my account to settings

Comment: isn't there any button for login? or are we just supposed to press enter?

Comment: I don't know about the UI. I don't use snaps. However, there should be a service running which proxies the user session bits over to snapd to perform the login, called snapd-login-service IIRC. There were apparently some changes to the packaging in 18.04 though, so maybe the service went away and gnome-online-accounts wasn't fixed. I'm not sure. Can you install snaps from inside the _Software_ application?

Comment: It's broken in the unity-control-center/unity session, i.e there is no connect button appearing. Not sure that it has any real value but if you must have it then you'd need to log into a ubuntu session & use gnome-control-center

Comment: Yes, I can do that. I think my problem is related to the UI

Comment: I installed gnome-control-center and tried. Even there, there is no button

Comment: let me ck., this came up a couple of weeks ago & I was able to see that button as described.

Comment: Still works in an ubuntu session, (which uses gnome-control-center i think), see https://0x0.st/sSeO.png  So you'd need to log into that session if it still exists. What do you need this for, I've found it to be useless after they removed the file sync service.

Comment: Just wanted to what Livepatch service is. It requires SSO sign in

Comment: well try in an ubuntu session, (re-install if needed), or can't you login to sso manually ( like I do for launchpad). Otherwise mentioned here, maybe bring up again & jump start some movement. https://community.ubuntu.com/t/testing-unity-session-in-18-04/987/133

Comment: Can confirm that if set up in an ubuntu session it'll show as been activated when going back to a unity session.

Comment: ok then i'll try it now

Comment: @doug It worked. Now write it as an answer so I can mark it correct :D

Comment: @doug It has nothing to do with file sync service, btw. This exists only as a UI for logging in via snapd. If you've already logged in via CLI with snap login, then the livepatch stuff from snapd should already work.

Comment: @dobey, I'm not the one you should be telling, as mentioned I've found SSO to be useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment setting up the SSO online account is broken in an unity session, the `connect` button to finish the set up doesn't appear.

As a workaround if the default ubuntu session is still installed one can log into that session, set up the SSO online account there. After returning to the preferred unity session you'll find it enabled.

If a fix arises word of it should appear in this thread below linked comment
https://community.ubuntu.com/t/testing-unity-session-in-18-04/987/156

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to add some online accounts you can add it by this

```
$ export GTK_CSD=1
$ unity-control-center
```

Then do it normal.
It's a bug from [gnome-online-accounts](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-online-accounts/issues/58), just wait it fixed.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I managed to solve the problem then by using GNOME shell. But now I can connect to SSO without enabling CSD, I think it is fixed now, even though the bug report doesn't mark it as solved.

Comment: I can confirm that this works